# bool object not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

hello I am making a command line based game engine and there is an error that keeps popping up it says 'TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable' when trying to run this code on line 233

```
232  #quest handler
233  for quest in active_quests not in completed_quests:
234    quest_type = data.quests[quest]["type"]
235    if quest_type == "kill":
236      #check if thing has been killed
237      if data.quests[quest]["number"] in fights_won:
238        unrewarded_quests.append(quest)
```

I do not know if it thinks that active_quests or completed_quests is a bool. as far as i know there are both lists. there values are as follows

```
completed_quests = [0]
active_quests = []
```

part of me thinks that because there is nothing in acitve_quests that it comes back as False
I want to know how to make it not brake if there is nothing in active_quests. as long as nothing goes wrong there should always be something in completed_quests.
full code can be found at replit and github.
github link: https://github.com/mrhoomanwastaken/pypg/tree/people-and-quest-handler-overhaul

replit link:
https://replit.com/@mrhoomanwastaken/pypg-game-engine?v=1

Comment: It looks like you're trying to iterate over "elements of `active_quests` that aren't in `completed_quests`". The `not in` operator doesn't work like that.

Comment: `active_quests not in completed_quests` Returns a boolean.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger! `active_quests not in completed_quests` returns a bool that you then try to loop over

Comment: You're trying to loop over `active_quests not in completed_quests`.  That's a boolean, probably always False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but your syntax was a bit off. You should iterate over a list of elements that satisfy your condition, but instead you were iterating over a boolean of the pattern `a not in b`.

```py
for quest in [q for q in active_quests if q not in completed_quests]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`active_quests not in completed_quests` returns a `bool`, which is why your code won't work.

The `for` loop should be rewritten to something like

```
for quest in [a for a in active_quests if a not in completed_quests]:
```

Comment: you should probably use a meaningful variable name instead of in-lining it